# Launching Xendesktop ICA session programmatically

Tags: citrix, citrix-access-gateway, xendesktop

I want to programmatically launch xendesktop and see whether it is launched or not for monitoring purposes.I understand that if somehow I can get the ica file then passing that ica file to ica client can solve my problem.
I read that citrix has ICO API but I am not able to use it to launch my desktop.
Can someone pls throw some light on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's wrong with the ICO API?

Answer (score 0):

ICO API in real-world scenarios is not enough.
You need to get your VDI address from StoreFront API https://github.com/citrix/storefront-sdk. Here you can download the whole ICA file and just launch it. I'm downloading it, modifying to run windowed and then just run ICA. Windows do the rest. The other possibility is to download ICA using StoreFront API, get Address from there and connect to the machine using this Address. It's actually IP and port for your VDI desktop.